# Assign to a function call like in C++11

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

In C++ one is allowed to return a reference to a value, and then write to is, for example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int data[] = {1,2,3,4};
  std::cout << data[0] << " " << data[1] << " " << data[2] << " " << data[3] << '\n';
  auto key =
    [](int data[]) -> int &
    {
      return data[1];
    };
  key(data) = 6;
  std::cout << data[0] << " " << data[1] << " " << data[2] << " " << data[3] << '\n';
}
```

This works, and the output of the C++11 code is:

```
1 2 3 4
1 6 3 4
```

Meanwhile, in Python 3:

```
data = (1,2,3,4)
key = lambda d: d[2]
key(data) = 5
print(data)
```

This works, but doesn't please, as it nicely states that I may not assign to function calls:

```
  File "gett.py", line 4
    key(data) = 5
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

So how do I pass a callable which can be used for both getting and setting? What is the Python 3 way of doing this?

My particular use case is that I have something like this:

```
#Data = namedtuple('Data',    ['meta', 'value', 'othervalue'])
# since namedtuples are not muteable

class Data:
  def __init__(self, meta, value, othervalue):
    self.meta = meta; self.value=value; self.othervalue=othervalue;

data = [Data('blabla', None, 543), Data('blabla', 5, 54), Data('blabla', 324, None), Data('blabla', None, 34), Data('blabla', 432, None)]
```

where I want replace each `None` with the previous value for either `value` or `othervalue`, like this:

```
def nearest_before_interpolate(self, l, key):
  last = 0
  for i in range(len(l)):
    with getattr(l[i], key) as val:
      if val == None:
        setattr(l[i], key, last)
      else:
        last = val
```

Now I pass the key as a string, but it would be nice if this was a generic `lambda` which can extract the right field in any fashion it sees fit (not that it really needs that flexibility, but I like `lambda`s more than strings I guess, and also better suited for this use case).

Does anyone have a good suggestion how to do this?

Comment: tuples are immutable, so your simplified example doesn't make sense.

Comment: The difference is that C++ allows functions to return something *that can be assigned to* - Python doesn't, so it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: >>> a[2] = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here:

- The python syntax doesn't allow direct assignment to the returned value of a function call - `can't assign to function call`. Simple as that.
- Tuples are immutable, so you can't replace an item, only change it's value. Which is clearly a problem in your symplified example - you can't change the value of a number.. 5 is 5.

Fixing those issues, here's a proof of concept:

```
data = ([1],[2],[3],[4])
key = lambda d: d[2]
v = key(data)
v.append(0)
print(data)  # ([1], [2], [3, 0], [4])
```

---

**Update**: sorry, I was a bit confused because you use tuple but then a list.

Well, you can almost do it, just not with the syntax you want:

```
class wrapper():
   def __init__(self, d, i):
     self.d = d
     self.i = i
   def set(self, v):
     self.d[self.i] = v

data = [1,2,3,4]
key = lambda d: wrapper(d, 2)
v = key(data)
v.set(5)
print(data)  # [1, 2, 5, 4]
```

In python you cannot overload assignment, so you need some other method to change the value. Here I picked a function call, but you can use anything that can be [intercepted](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) (e.g.: setting an attribute).

Comment: Well, here key returns a list, to which you can append and which you can change, but you can't overwrite the whole thing with something else for example. This only works, I would think, if key returns a pointer-like-type, like a list, but not an element of that list.

Comment: That is: data = [1,2,3,4]; key = lambda x: x[1]; v = key(data); v=5; print(data)   results in [1,2,3,4]

Comment: It works with anything that's mutable, as long as you don't do an *assignment*. Your example was a bit confusing (tuple vs list), give me some time...

Comment: hrrmrr :( Your updated solution is a bit java-ish, especially since you can also use a wrapper object which isn't really transparent (like proxies in c++11). Thank you for your efforts though. My question isn't limited to lists nor to tuples, it should be applicable to anything you can store in python. In general one could how you can store a writeable reference in python, which your wrapper class basically tries to be for a list.

Comment: I'm afraid (or rather glad) there is nothing in the language that supports that. Once you get an element from the container, you already left the territory of the container...

Comment: Why are you rather glad about it?

Comment: Because it makes the language simpler, and the code easier to read. A variable is just a handle/pointer to the actual object. If you do an assignment you simply point it to something else. References would just add a lot of headaches...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the closest you can get without major hackery:

```
class Data(object):

    def __init__(self, meta, value, othervalue):
        self.meta = meta
        self.value = value
        self.othervalue = othervalue

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        setattr(self, key, value)


d = Data('blabla', None, 543)
print d.value                       # None
d['value'] = 321
print d.value                       # 321
```

Comment: That would be a lot of boilerplate code, moreover, I may want to use one type of access for a data type at one moment, and another one at another time. If you want to separate the getter and setter, it is better to pass a get-lambda and a set-lambda, instead of your OO implementation, since the getting and setting implementation should be defined per-call and not per-type.

Comment: @Herbert I don’t *want* to separate them, it’s just that there is no way around that, as others have pointed out. You could write a generic wrapper class that is instantiated with a get-lambda and a set-lambda (or any other kind of logic) and provides the appropriate `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.